# java arrays and creating them

Tags: java, arrays, int

I'm currently in programming in java and I cannot for the life of me understand what is going on here.  If any of you could point me in the right direction that would be wonderful.

These are the directions:

Make an instance variable for an integer array.
The ArrayLab constructor will take an integer parameter that will be the number of elements in the array. Create the array inside your constructor. DO NOT save the int parameter as an instance variable.

And this is what I have for code.  It obviously doesn't work right, but I have no idea where to go from here.

```
 private int[] integerArray;

public ArrayLab(int inParameter){
    integerArray = integerArray[inParameter];
}
```

Comment: [When you _have no idea where to go from here_, you generally read a book or a tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Look up the keyword `new`.

Comment: integerArray = new integerArray[inParameter];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyword `new` is used to create Object.
You can doing something like...

```
public class ArrayLab {
   private int[] integerArray;

   public ArrayLab(int inParameter) {
       this.integerArray = new int[inParameter];   //Creates arrays of integer of length inParameter.
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are only needed to add `new` key word when you created an array.

```
private int[] integerArray;

public ArrayLab(int inParameter){
    integerArray = new int[inParameter];
}
```

Comment: integerArray is not a datatype its just a variable name. May be you mean something like 'new int[inParameter]'

Comment: Off course I meant that. Gosh! I cannot believe I did such a mistake here. @ParthSatra